# Terraform 0.12 main.tfvars variables not visible in tf.var

Tags: terraform

For example in main.tfvars I have declared variable

```
cid = "xyz"
```

In main.tf i am trying to use it as follow.

```
resource "xyzresource" "example"{
clientID=var.cid }
```

However it doesnt recognize it, rather it asks from stdin to pass the value to var.cid
If someone can assist will be helpful. thx

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, you're just missing a variable declaration like the following

```
variable "cid" {
  type = string
}
```

`tfvars` if for specifying the *values* of varibles whereas a `variable` block (like above) is for *declaring* that a variable exists.

You could put this `variable` declaration in your `main.tf` but it's also common to add another file next to `main.tf` called `variables.tf` that contains all variable declarations.

For more information, the [terraform docs on input variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) are actually pretty good.